# ¿Cómo importo la primera fila y un rango de celdas de un archivo?

Tags: python, excel, importación, openpyxl

estoy tratando de importar la primera fila y un rango de celdas de una hoja excel, pero no logro hacerlo.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np
import time

data = pd.read_excel (r'C://Trabajo//database_sept2020.xlsx', sheet_name='data MAE')

data_rows = []
for row in data['A2':'AJ84']:
    data_cols = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
#print (df)
```

Luego de ejecutar el código que muestro, me aparece este error:

> cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [A2] of type str

EDIT!!
Ahora ocupo la siguiente forma y me arroja el mismo error anterior

````
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C://Trabajo//database_sept2020.xlsx')#, sheet_name='data MAE')
hoja = doc.get_sheet_by_name('data MAE')
hoja = data['A2':'AJ84']```
````

Comment: ¿en qué línea te da el error?

Comment: En este for 
for row in data['A2':'AJ84']:

Comment: es que iterar con `for row in data['A2':'AJ84']:` no tiene ningún sentido :) Tiene que ser una sintaxis válida de Python y esta no lo es.

Comment: Perfecto, lo hice de la segunda forma y me arroja el mismo error, si quiere puede ver el EDIT que hice

Answer (score 2):

Para seleccionar un rango de columnas de un DataFrame debes usar [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) o [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Si querés seleccionar columnas por su nombre deberías usar **loc** pasandole el nombre de las columnas que querés seleccionar:

```
data = pd.read_excel (r'C://Trabajo//database_sept2020.xlsx', sheet_name='data MAE')
columns = ["A2","A3", ...,"AJ84"] # notá que los 3 puntos los puse para no escribir todas las columnas, no es válido usar los 3 puntos.
data.loc[0,columns]
```

En tu caso lo mejor sería usar índices (**iloc**) para seleccionar las columnas, ya que son muchas.
Supongamos que **A1** está en la posición 0, **A2** está en la posición 1 y **AJ84** en la posición 200, entonces deberías hacer:

```
data = pd.read_excel (r'C://Trabajo//database_sept2020.xlsx', sheet_name='data MAE')
data.iloc[0,1:201]
# data.iloc[0,1:] si AJ84 es la última podes hacerlo de ésta forma
```

El 0 en los dos ejemplos corresponde al número de fila.

Lee [acá](https://www.analyticslane.com/2019/06/21/seleccionar-filas-y-columnas-en-pandas-con-iloc-y-loc/) más información acerca de cómo seleccionar filas y columnas de un DataFrame.

Comment: Esto me funcionó, muchas gracias!!